# Wpf dynamic menu and submenu using xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to dynamic menu and submenu using pure xaml not code behind. I tried below code:

```
<Menu Grid.Row="1" 
      Background="Transparent" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding MenuList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <Menu.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Menu.ItemsPanel>

    <Menu.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <MenuItem Style="{StaticResource mainMenu}" 
                      Background="Transparent" 
                      Command="{Binding NavigateToView}" 
                      >
                <MenuItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Rectangle Width="30" Height="30" Fill="White" Margin="0,0,10,0">
                            <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{DynamicResource appbar_add}" />
                            </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <TextBlock Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="18" Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </MenuItem.Header>
            </MenuItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Menu.ItemTemplate>
</Menu>
```

My Menu and Submenu class looks like this:

```
public class DynamicMenuListModel : BaseModel
{
    public int MenuId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ViewName { get; set; }
    public bool HasChildMenu { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    public List<DynamicSubmenuMenuListModel> SubMenus { get; set; }
}

public class DynamicSubmenuMenuListModel : BaseModel
{
    public int SubMenuId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ViewName { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
}
```

Menu is created successfully but the design is totally different from the static menu that I had previously implemented. Here is the code for my previous implementation with static data:

```
<Menu Grid.Row="1" Background="Transparent">
    <Menu.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Menu.ItemsPanel>

    <MenuItem Background="Transparent" Style="{StaticResource mainMenu}">
        <MenuItem.Header>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle Width="30" Height="30" Fill="White" Margin="0,0,10,0">
                    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{DynamicResource appbar_home_location_round}" />
                    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                </Rectangle>
                <TextBlock Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="18">Location</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </MenuItem.Header>
        <MenuItem Width="250"  Command="{Binding LoadCountry}" Background="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" Foreground="White" Header="Country">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <Rectangle Width="10" Height="10" Fill="White" Margin="5,0,10,0">
                    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{DynamicResource appbar_moon_full}" />
                    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                </Rectangle>
            </MenuItem.Icon>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Background="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" Command="{Binding LoadState}" Foreground="White" Header="State">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <Rectangle Width="10" Height="10" Fill="White" Margin="5,0,10,0">
                    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{DynamicResource appbar_moon_full}" />
                    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                </Rectangle>
            </MenuItem.Icon>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Command="{Binding LoadCity}" Background="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" Foreground="White" Header="City">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <Rectangle Width="10" Height="10" Fill="White" Margin="5,0,10,0">
                    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{DynamicResource appbar_moon_full}" />
                    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                </Rectangle>
            </MenuItem.Icon>
        </MenuItem>
    </MenuItem>
<Menu>
```

Also, when I bind data using Observable collection then Command is not working. I don't know how to figure out this and is there a much cleaner way to bind dynamic data to Menu without using code behind? I have reviewed other post on stack overflow but no clear implementation is provided yet.